# whenever I write a line of text, is there a way to display current time stamp to the left on sublime text?

Tags: sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

On sublime text, i often write text at various intervals.

Every time i write, a time stamp should appear with current time to the left indicating, i wrote it at that particular time instance.

is anyone aware of any 3rd scripts or tools that work with sublime text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few years ago I wrote a plugin called `InsertDateTime` and never got around to submitting it to `Package Control`. I'll try and get it submitted soon but the admins generally take a few weeks to add submitted plugins.

However in the meantime you can install it manually, download it from here:

[InsertDateTime - Plugin for Sublime Text](https://github.com/mattst/InsertDateTime).

Comment: That's a nice project. Thank you